# 'Page not found' but hook_menu() is correct!

Tags: 7, hooks, uri

This is my `hook_menu`:

```
$items['events/%event'] = array(
  'title' => 'Event',
  'title callback' => 'entity_label',
  'title arguments' => array('event', 1),
  'page callback' => 'events_view',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => 'entity_access',
  'access arguments' => array('view', 'event', 1),
  'file' => 'events.pages.inc',
);

return $items;
```

But when I navigate to `events/2` there's a 404 error waiting! Here's the page:

[image: Page not found!]

As you can see, my `Event` has been successfully created (it exists in database and its `id` is definitely `2`) but the requested page could not be found and `Shortcuts` menu and `Navigation` block has disappeared.
What possibly could I mistaken?
Feel free to ask for more information.
Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm using Drupal 7.12

Comment: Why are you trying to access the path shamsi/events/2? Why would that work?

Comment: I didn't understand your question! This is the address: `localhost/shamsi/events/2` and the corresponding uri in `hook_menu` would be: `events/%event`. Right?

Comment: @Letharion The site's probably installed in a sub-folder of the web root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're getting a 404 it's due to one of the following:

- You haven't cleared Drupal's cache since you implemented the menu item, OR
- Your `event_load()` function is returning FALSE/NULL for the provided ID, OR
- The function `event_load()` doesn't actually exist

Judging from the rest of your function/file names (`events_view`, `events.pages.inc`) your module is called `events` so your router load function will probably be called `events_load()` (note the additional `s`).

If that's true then you need to change your menu item to match that:

```
$items['events/%events'] = array(
  // ...
```

And clear Drupal's cache to pick up the change.

Comment: Good sight.
I didn't notice that `s`.
Thanks. Problem solved immediately :)

Comment: @PedramBehroozi No problem, I make so many spelling mistakes myself writing code it's always the first place I look!

Comment: This is correct: The placeholder name is used as name for the function to load the object, to which is added "_load"; if the placeholder is "%event_node," for example, then Drupal will look for the `event_node_load()`. If that function doesn't exist, then all users will get a 404 error.